# Radio Button Group with the same name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this problem: In my form i have one list of questions and this questions have multiples answers with radio buttons that have the same name.

If i have one question, no problem, but if i have two or more questions i have a lot of radio buttons with the same name.

I have this in HTML:

```
<label>Do you Like?</label>
<label>Yes</label>
<input type="radio" value="35" name="answer">
<label>No</label>
<input type="radio" value="36" name="answer">

<label>Are you interested?</label>
<label>Yes</label>
<input type="radio" value="35" name="answer">
<label>No</label>
<input type="radio" value="36" name="answer">

<label>Do you like repeat?</label>
<label>Yes</label>
<input type="radio" value="35" name="answer">
<label>No</label>
<input type="radio" value="36" name="answer">
```

I can't change the name or the value, because i need this properties to save the answer of the user.

The user select one radio and if the user select other radio of the other question, the radio of the first question change and show only one radio selected.

Comment: Why can't you give it a different name again? That makes no sense?

Comment: Because is a List and i need the same name to save the answer ....

Comment: _"I can't change the name or the value, because i need this properties to save the answer of the user."_ makes non sense.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a different name for the radio buttons in each question. Radio buttons with the same name can only be used as one "group." Example:

```
<label>Do you Like?</label>
<label>Yes</label>
<input type="radio" value="35" name="like_answer">
<label>No</label>
<input type="radio" value="36" name="like_answer">

<label>Are you interested?</label>
<label>Yes</label>
<input type="radio" value="35" name="interested_answer">
<label>No</label>
<input type="radio" value="36" name="interested_answer">
```

Answer (score -1):

change `name`

```
<label>Do you Like?</label>
<label>Yes</label>
<input type="radio" value="35" name="answer">
<label>No</label>
<input type="radio" value="36" name="answer">

<label>Are you interested?</label>
<label>Yes</label>
<input type="radio" value="35" name="answertwo">
<label>No</label>
<input type="radio" value="36" name="answertwo">

<label>Do you like repeat?</label>
<label>Yes</label>
<input type="radio" value="35" name="answertree">
<label>No</label>
<input type="radio" value="36" name="answertree">
```

Comment: It is explicitly said that he couldn't change the name